# App rotates on all iPads except for iPad 2

Tags: ios, ipad-2

I have a universal app that works fine on all hardware except for iPad 2. On that device the app doesn't rotate, it's always locked to portrait. On other iPad hardware it rotates fine, and running the same version of iOS (9.3) on other hardware doesn't exhibit this issue, it's just on iPad 2.

The correct orientations are set up in the plist file. I tried changing the iPhone orientations to see if the iPad 2 was reading the wrong key but that didn't make a difference. I've also verified that the system is reading the orientation correctly (via `UIDevice.currentDevice.orientation`).

I also know it's not just our hardware or a simulator bug, as we've had several reports from the wild confirming the issue.

I've never heard of something like this before

Comment: May it help you - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7792745

Comment: Looks like a similar but not the same issue. It's not that all apps won't rotate, it's just my app that doesn't rotate. Other apps work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a lock symbol at the top of the screen next to the battery indicator ? If there is, then depending on what you've got Settings > General > Use Side Switch To set to (rotation lock or mute notifications), then you can lock/unlock the rotation by the switch on the right hand side of the iPad above the volume switch, or via the taskbar : double-click the home button; slide from the left; and it's the icon far left; press home again to exit the taskbar. The function that isn't on the side switch is set via the taskbar instead : http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4085

If there isn't a lock symbol then try a reset : press and hold both the sleep and home buttons for about 10 to 15 seconds (ignore the red slider), after which the Apple logo should appear - you won't lose any content, it's the iPad equivalent of a reboot.